# How do I display RAM usage in top bar (gnome shell)?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ram

I'm looking for numbers like "2.4 GB" used not percentages or graphs like the GNOME shell extension called "system-monitor" does.

Answer (score 2):

Use the System Monitor Extension or Multiload.

[Multiload](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload) is installed by

```
sudo apt install indicator-multiload
```

Launch the System Load Indicator app, select Preferences, then Indicator Items, and put Memory at the top.

[System Monitor Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) requires this installation first:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0, gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 chrome-gnome-shell
```

Once those dependencies are satisfied, [install the extension](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/blob/master/README.md) and set your preference to show memory used, [as shown here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/03/display-cpu-memory-network-usage-in-ubuntu-18-04-panel/).